# StackPanel orientation not fully horizontal on ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, itemscontrol, stackpanel

I have the following issue. 
i'm using Items control and I dont understand why my result is on several lines instead of being on a single line. 
This is my code :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,10,10,10">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="TabCountries" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Name="Country" Text="{Binding nom}" Style="{StaticResource whiteFontColor}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,0,5,0" Name="isCountryAllowed" IsChecked="{Binding isAllowed}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

The result is like that :

```
FR
BE
AN
```

instead of being like that:

```
FR BE AN ...
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not change the layout of the items, only the layout of the `ItemsControl` as a whole (which does almost nothing if there are no other elements in the same `StackPanel`).

Use [`ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) to make the items layout horizontally.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```